# How to conditionally buffer in RX

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I am trying to load a log file as a stream, so I can get a live log tailer working via web.

It should load the historical lines to date from the logfile and then fire updates for every new line that gets saved.

To reduce signalR traffic, I am batching them up into lots of 100 lines using the RX Buffer, however this is a problem when loading the initial file contents - which could be 100k lines. Loading this in batches of 100 is too slow. The initial file contents should be sent as a single message.

What I really want is to send a single tick on the Observable first with the entire contents of the file to date, and then from that point, fire buffered updates for new line writes. But I'm not sure how to get the initial content through as a single tick and then buffer from then onwards.

My code so far

```
var watcherSubject = new ReplaySubject<LogTailMessage>()
var watcher = new logFileWatcher(logFileLocation)
new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => watcher.StartFileWatch(data => watcherSubject.OnNext(data), CancellationToken.None));

Stream = watcherSubject
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 100)
    .Where(d => d != null)
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();
```

Updated solution

```
var initialFileLines = watcher.GetInitialData();

new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => watcher.StartFileWatcher(data => watcherSubject.OnNext(data), _cts.Token));

Stream = watcherSubject.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 100)
    .StartWith(initialFileLines)
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`StartWith`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#StartWith):

```
var originalFileLines = new List<LogTailMessage>(); //Initialize with file contents.

Stream = watcherSubject
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 100)
    .Where(d => d != null)
    .StartWith(originalFileLines)
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();
```

---

**Update**: I'm not sure why `StartWith` isn't working reliably. Can you modify answer with a mocked example?

`.Concat` should work, though I think this is basically just what `StartWith` is supposed to do.:

```
Stream = Observable.Return(originalFileLines).Concat(
    watcherSubject
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 100)
        .Where(d => d != null)
        .Replay()
        .RefCount()
   );
```

Comment: I've implemented it like you said - the initial data is loaded synchronously before I even start the Task which watches for new lines. However in some cases when there are file updates at the same time as I start up the log tailer, I see there are 2-3 update ticks from the 500ms buffer, before the initial data ticks (when the initial data is say 20,000 entries). I would have thought StartWith would guarantee that the first observable tick you would get would be that data. Is there a race condition involved?

Comment: Is it because the Buffer timer takes precedence?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised at that. Updated answer.